# Change position of elements 1:2 in a vector

Tags: r, vector

**I have this vector:**

```
vector_have <- c("A", "B", "C", "A1", "B2", "C3")

[1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "A1" "B2" "C3"
```

**I would like to get:**

```
vector_wanted <- c("A1", "A", "B2", "B", "C3", "C")

[1] "A1" "A"  "B2" "B"  "C3" "C"
```

**I have tried:**

```
sort(vector_have)

[1] "A"  "A1" "B"  "B2" "C"  "C3"
```

Now I would like to switch the position of each second element to the preceding one.

I think it must be done with TRUE, FALSE iteratively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `mixed_sort` does it

```
gtools::mixedsort(vector_have)
[1] "A1" "A"  "B2" "B"  "C3" "C"
```

---

Or if it is based on the position, another option is `matrix`

```
 c(matrix(vector_have, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)[2:1,])
[1] "A1" "A"  "B2" "B"  "C3" "C"
```

Comment: Perfect. I thought there must be a ifelse TRUE, FALSE solution ?

Comment: @TarJae based on the position matching, I think `matrix` based approach would be easier compared to recycling of logical vectors

Comment: It appears `gtools::mixedsort` Browse[2]> ord
[1] 4 1 5 2 6 3` views as positional. x[ord]

Comment: @Chris you meant `mixedorder`?

Comment: debugonce(gtools::mixedsort), returns x[ord], and yes, from a further call to `ord <- mixedorder(`; as they say, reading [fully] is fundamental.